# Understanding a proof of a lemma in elliptic surfaces

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, algebraic-surfaces, curves-and-surfaces, elliptic-surfaces

In the following paper , [The Kahler-Ricci flow on surfaces of positive Kodaira dimension](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/cheltsov/cambridge/pdf/tian07.pdf) (Sung and Tian) in page  621, I am trying to understand the proof of part 1 of Lemma 3.4.

In the part 1 of proof of inequality the authors first use of logarithmic transformation due to Kodaira. After they directly say

"Therefore $ω_{SF}$ is a **smooth** family of Ricci-flat metrics **over $B$**".
I can not see this fact from Logarithmic transformation. Can you explain more?

In the first part of proof they define $\tilde Y=\mathbb C\times \tilde B/L$, BUT I think we must define $\tilde Y=\mathbb C\times  B/L$. For instance see this [paper](http://www.math.nyu.edu/~tschinke/papers/yuri/04ellhyp/ellhyp6.pdf)

In final the strategy of proof is not clear for me. I need to more details.

Comment: What paper?  What page?

Comment: You may look at the Gross-Wilson paper on Large complex structure limits of $K3$ surfaces. They discussed the semi-flat metric in great detail. This is the standard Gibbons-Hawking construction.

Comment: Thanks user43423, But I couldn't find any connection ,you can explain more

Comment: Perhaps your advisor can provide you with more details, since he wrote the paper?